# How can i convert word document to xml using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Please give an idea for convert doc file to xml using codeigniter .I have tried a lot . But i didn't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, doc file - is closed binary file and you cannot parse it without third party libraries. `Codeigniter` have not any tools or helpers to to that. So, you need to search for `com` libraries from Microsoft or Open Office and use them.

---

Fro building `xml` file I recommend you to look at [FluidXML](https://github.com/servo-php/fluidxml)

Comment: How to use com in codeigniter.I  have tried.but i didn't get it.

Comment: In `Codeigniter` - nohow. But, `PHP` can. Try a library such as PHPWord (old CodePlex site).